# Create ExtensionMethod for ICollection accepting inherited collection types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, extension-methods

I am creating a class that could accept a generic type as data, and, in case of being a collection type, I would like to create an extension method for Add elements inside. By now, I have the following extension method:

```
public ActionResponseBuilder<ICollection<TElement>> AddElement<TElement>(this ActionResponseBuilder<ICollection<TElement>> builder, TElement element)
{
    //TODO Logic
    return builder;
}
```

My test method for this:

```
var data = DateTime.Now;

var builtActionResponse = new ActionResponseBuilder<List<DateTime>>()
       .SetData(new List<DateTime> { data })
       .AddElement(data)
       .Build();
```

But I am having the following error:

> Error CS1929  'ActionResponseBuilder>' does not contain a definition for 'AddElement' and the best extension method overload 'ActionResponseBuilderHelper.AddElement(ActionResponseBuilder>, DateTime)' requires a receiver of type 'ActionResponseBuilder>

If I change the type for the extension method to List, it works but I would like to take advantage and the power of the inheritance and generics for this,

What I am missing, can I do this? Any idea?

Thank you a lot in advance :)

***PD***: This things are part of a small nuget tool, all the code except this new implementation could be found at the following GitHub repository:

- https://github.com/Xelit3/CommonNET

***EDIT***: Initially, the name of the extension method was wrong copied AddData -> AddElement, thanks to @Fabjan

Comment: Where do u call AddData extension?

Comment: Hello! After calling one of the builder methods that are sending back the same object, in this moment the object type is declared. If in my extension method I change ICollection by List, it works but it is not the best approach I want

Comment: Your extension method is called 'AddData' and **not** 'AddElement'

Comment: thanks you are right, I edit the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your extension method to take both T and TElement and constrain T to force it to be an ICollection:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ActionResponseBuilder<T> AddData<T, TElement>(this ActionResponseBuilder<T> builder, TElement element) where T : ICollection<TElement>
    {
        // TODO: Logic

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Now you can reference it like this:

```
ActionResponseBuilder<List<DateTime>> builder = new ActionResponseBuilder<List<DateTime>>()
    .AddData(DateTime.Now);
```